# How to add Tukey result above barplot? [not using ggplot]

Tags: r, bar-chart, vegan

Im trying to add the significance results of my Tukey test as my colunms label (a simply letter "a" "ab" "b" above each colunm)... I've seen examples using the ggplot pack but Im still a R begginer and so Im using a simply barplot function. Is it even possible to add labels above the colunms? What code can I try to use?

Here's the code Im using:

```
data <- read_xlsx("Peixesz.xlsx", sheet = "MATRIZamb", col_names = TRUE)

str(data)

anovaph <- aov(pH ~ data$Season, data= data)

meanph <- with(data,tapply(pH,data$Season,mean)) 
stdevph <- with(data,tapply(pH,data$Season,sd))

TukeyHSD(anovaph)

x <- barplot(meanph,beside=T,ylim=c(0,10),width=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), ylab="pH",xlab="Season)
arrows(x0=x,y0=meanph-stdevph,
       x1=x,y1=meanph+stdevph,
       angle=90,length=0.14,code=3)
```

At the barplot: Colunms are my means values of pH along each season (Winter, Autumn, Spring, Summer) AND the bar above is the standard deviation for each mean value.

Here's my Tukey test result:

```
> (HSD.test(anovaph, "data$Season")) 
$statistics
    MSerror Df     Mean       CV
  0.1834646 31 7.670857 5.583831

$parameters
   test        name.t ntr StudentizedRange alpha
  Tukey data$Season  4         3.838277  0.05

$means
                 pH       std  r  Min  Max    Q25   Q50    Q75
Winter     8.100000 0.1796823  8 7.86 8.33 7.9600 8.125 8.2450
Autumn     7.561250 0.6256068  8 6.13 8.15 7.5025 7.745 7.9025
Spring     7.652000 0.4210780 10 6.70 8.09 7.5825 7.680 7.9550
Summer     7.407778 0.3751592  9 6.89 7.95 7.1200 7.410 7.7200

$comparison
NULL

$groups
                pH  groups
Winter     8.100000      a
Spring     7.652000     ab
Autumn     7.561250     ab
Summer     7.407778      b

attr(,"class")
[1] "group"
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Something like `mctest <- HSD.test(anovaph, "data$Season"); text(x, meanph, mctest$groups$groups, pos=3)` should do it as long as there is enough space at the top of the highest bar.